# C++ :- Replacing a piece of string by another string

Tags: c++, string, data-structures, replace

I am trying to write a `REPLACE` function that will replace the `given` string by the `required`string. When I am dry running the function on paper, everything seems to be fine but while executing, it's not giving the correct output. The code is as follows:-

```
string REPLACE(string src,string reqd,string given)
{
    int i,j,k;
    int pos = FIND(src,given);
    if(pos==-1)
        return "";
    else
    {
        char *arr = new char[src.length()+reqd.length()-given.length()];  // creating the array that will hold the modified string
        for(i=0;i<pos;i++)
            arr[i] = src[i];     // copying the initial part of the string
        for(i=pos,j=0;i<pos+reqd.length()+1&&j<reqd.length();i++,j++)
            arr[i] = reqd[j];    // copying the required string into array
        for(i=pos+reqd.length()+1,k=0;i<sizeof(arr);i++,k++)
            arr[i] = src[pos+given.length()+k];   // copying the remaining part of source string into the array
        return arr;
    }   
}
```

Here the `FIND` is also written by me and has been tested in many cases. I don't see any error in `FIND`.

Comment: Why are you manually allocating memory? Isn't `std:string` good enough? You also leak memory every time you call this function.

Comment: But then, I cannot make the string flexible enough to handle modifications that change their lengths.

Comment: Yes you can, use `std::string arr(src.length()+reqd.length()-given.length(), 0);`.

Comment: Sure you can,`std::string` is a dynamic container that can change its size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(i=pos+reqd.length()+1,k=0; i<sizeof(arr); i++,k++)
//                               ^^^^^^^^^^^
//                           This is always the same
```

`sizeof(arr)` is the same as `sizeof(char*)`, a compile-time constant value. You need to keep the size of a dynamically allocated array yourself (or, better yet, simply use `std::string` instead).

Comment: Works fine if I replace `sizeof(arr)` by `src.length()+reqd.length()-given.length()+1`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is a good idea to mix std::string with char arrays. Following should work:

```
string REPLACE(string src,string reqd,string given)
{
    int pos = FIND(src,given);

    src.replace( pos, given.size(), reqd );
    return src;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Could you please elaborate on why using `char` arrays and string together is a bad idea?

Comment: The class std::string itself can be used like a char array if required. Other than that, as already shown, it provides a lot more functionality and clarity to your code. It also automatically takes care of dynamic memory allocation without the fear of memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do not want to re-invent the wheel:

```
string REPLACE(string src,string reqd,string given)
{
    string str(src);
    size_t pos = str.find(given);
    if(pos == std::string::npos)
        return "";
    str.replace(pos, given.length(), reqd);
    return str;
}
```